# React testing library render complete doc

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library, ts-jest

Before starting here are a couple versions of the technologies we use

Typesript 5.3.3
React: 18.2.0
ts-jest: 29.1.2

I have a 3rd party ui design (company proprietary) installed as a node module.
Let's assume Foo.tsx:

```js
import React from 'react'
import '@company/lib'
export const Foo:React.FC=()=>{
  return <company-lib-bar items={[{name:'hello'},{name:'world'}]} />
}
```

the company library return the objects as

```html
<div data-testid='name-list'>
  <div data-testid='name'>hello</div>
  <div data-testid='name'>world</div>
</div>
```

using testing-library/react

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import {Foo} from './Foo'
describe('NavigationVertical component', () => {
 it('render',()=>{
   const {debug}=render(<Foo />)
   debug()
 })
})
```

in the console I get:
`<body><div><company-lib-bar items={[{name:'hello'},{name:'world'}]} /></div></body>`

So the question is the following:
Is there a way to render the complete doc ? I would like to have this as a result of debug():

```html
<body>
<div>
<div data-testid='name-list'>
  <div data-testid='name'>hello</div>
  <div data-testid='name'>world</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: Try `screen.debug()`

Comment: The `debug()` returns the result as expected. I can't reproduce.

Comment: @LinDu have you tried with a `@company-lib` being a node module ? if so, could you provide me your config ?

Comment: No, I created a module in a folder, not install it in `node_modules`. Show the code of the `@company-lib` if this cause the issue.

Comment: @LinDu Unfortunatly I can't do that. if it helps when importing it. It's not like material ui, We have all the tags in lower cas available. I don't really now how, but that's how it is. maybe you know a couple keywords I could look for ?

Comment: Ok. You cannot show the code of the company. Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example